# Integrating Facebook into an Android app for advertising via Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have an existing Android app which I am trying to advertise via Facebook ads. Facebook said I must integrate their library into my app, starting with downloading their SDK.

When I downloaded their SDK from here: http://developers.facebook.com/android/ there was no .jar files in it but examples of apps using their classes.

I think for my purposes I just need to make a call to Facebook when my app starts up, right? Because I don't want any Facebook functionality. I just want to be able to intgrate enough to b able to advertise in their system.

Could anyone please help me understand what I need to do?

Should I just copy all the classes in their Facebook/com/src folder into my own project? And if so, where do I add the access key and secret key for my Facebook app into my Android app?

Thanks!
- Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook SDK is not a simple jar file, but is instead an Android Library. If you're using eclipse, you need to import the SDK into your workspace, and add it as a library to your project.

See the google docs on how to add a library http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

And also the Facebook SDK Getting Started guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/